# How can I set background color of SwiftUI List Header in safe area in Landscape?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-list

I am trying to set the background of the safe area for a list header in landscape and I can't seem to change the default dark gray.  I can change it for rows but not for the header.  I don't want to use the GroupedListStyle.  Just want a normal list but to change the safe area background:

```
List {
    Section(header:
                HStack {
                    SearchBar()
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .background(Color.white)
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))

    ) {
        ...
    }
}
```

[image]

I have tried setting background with .edgesIgnoringSafeArea and also to use the ZStack approach but the dark gray is from the actual header and I can't find anyway to override it in landscape.

Answer (score 0):

Apply list style plain explicitly to fix it for all modes (tested with Xcode 13 / iOS 15)

```
List {
   // header here
   // content here
}
.listStyle(.plain)     // << here !!
```